# Uncaught Error: The entity being edited (postType, undefined) does not have a loaded config

Tags: block-editor

I'd like to target the default slug when creating a new page or post but I'm not getting too far. This is what I have so far in a file called `custom-wp-gutenberg.js`

```
wp.domReady( function() {
    const default_slug = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostSlug( 'slug' );
    const custom_slug = wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost( { slug: 'new-title' } );
} );
```

I'm enqueueing the file like so:

```
function rh_dequeue_admin_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-wp-gutenberg', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'js/custom-wp-gutenberg.js', array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-data', 'wp-editor', 'react', 'react-dom' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-wp-gutenberg' );
    
    do_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rh_dequeue_admin_scripts' );
```

It generates the console error `Uncaught Error: The entity being edited (postType, undefined) does not have a loaded config.`

What am I missing?